# ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed for FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I want to generate a `:stake` factory that belongs to a `:topic` and a `:group`. The `:topic` should belong to a `:group` (as `:owner_group`) and in this case it should be the same `:group` (as the one `:stake` belongs to). Topic also belongs to `:membership`. In short, I want this to set up valid objects:

```
it 'should set up all the factories' do
  member = FactoryGirl.create(:membership)
  topic  = FactoryGirl.create(:topic, owner_group: member.group, membership: member)
  stake  = FactoryGirl.create(:stake, group: member.group, topic: topic)
end
```

But I get the error:

> Failure/Error: stake = FactoryGirl.create(:stake, group:
>   member.group, topic: topic) ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
>   Validation failed: Group has already been taken

Here are my factories:

```
factory :user
  sequence(:email) { |n| "foo#{n}@bar.com" }
end

factory :group
  name Faker::Company.name

  factory :owner_group
  end
end

factory :membership
  user
  group
end

factory :topic
  owner_group
  membership
end

factory :stake
  group
  topic
end
```

**topic.rb** has this association:

```
belongs_to :owner_group, class_name: "Group", foreign_key: "group_id"
```

I've remedied similar errors in the past with **rake db:test:prepare**, which doesn't work. I've also configured spec_helper.rb with the database_cleaner gem. So I suspect it's how I've set up my factories.

Is there anything in my factory associations or the way I'm creating the objects that's causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it sounds like there is already a `Stake` with that same `Group`. I don't see a problem with the factory definition. I would check your test database to make sure the `stakes` table is empty, but that's probably not the issue. Do you have a `before` block that is creating a `Stake`? Or perhaps `Topic` or `Group` have an `after_create` callback that creates an initial `Stake` automatically?

Comment: I had an after_create on topic that made a stake. Thank you so much, this was driving me insane.